# Google drive Upload returns - (403) Insufficient Permission

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to google drive using service account, but i am getting error like

> (403) Insufficient Permission error

Although fetching list of files from drive is working fine.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$service_account_name = '251181790499-1en2vs6jjovga1egu15tphm1m7g44m60@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'key.p12'; //key.p12

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);;

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    //$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    //$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
    $key);

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");

    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle(uniqid().'.jpg');
    $file->setDescription('A test document');
    $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

    $data = file_get_contents('a.jpg');

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
          'data' => $data,
          'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
          'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

    print_r($createdFile);

} 
else
{
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/googledrive/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I have reviewed similar questions in forum and tried suggestions but nothing seems to work.

Is there anything wrong with code?

Comment: Did you grant the service account permission to access the file?

Comment: Under the permissions tab Service account has by default "Can Edit" permissions. Is there anything i have to do?

Comment: $key_file_location   <--- should probably be the full path to the file.

Comment: i can try, but does it matter if both files(key file and the file where code is) are on same path?

Comment: what does file_get_contents return?  Is it finding the file?   that scope should be giving you full access and you are uploading to the service accounts google drive account so my first comment is invalid you should have access.   It must be an authentication issue.

Comment: file_get_contents returning content of key file which is nonreadable. I can fetch list of content from google drive also. Is there different permissions required to upload

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes  the one you are using should give you full power.

Comment: Thanks Dalm, seems to be caching issue :(  I got link of file in response but it's not visible in google drive now

Comment: Remember you are uploading to the service accounts google drive account.   If you want to be able to see it from your own Google drive account you are going to have to do an insert of the permissions.  to give yourself access

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert  then you can grant yourself access to the file on the service accounts drive account.

Comment: ok got it, So once i set permissions files would be visible under "Shared with me" folder on drive instead of "My Drive"

Answer (score 4):

Change your Google Drive Scope to

```
Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE
```

in PHP

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
```