# How to use Google Drive API to download files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to download files from google drive with javascript API. I have managed to authenticate and load list of files using `gapi.client.drive.files` request. However, I stuck at downloading those files.
My attempt to download the file:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId:id,
        alt:'media'
});
request.execute(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
});
```

I have these errors when trying to run the above:

```
(403) The user has not granted the app 336423653212 read access to the file 0B0UFTVo1BFVmeURrWnpDSloxQlE.

(400) Bad Request
```

I recognize that the files which aren't google drive file (google doc, google slide) return the 403 error. 
I am new to this. Any help and answer is really appreciated.

**Update 0**

From Google Drive documentation about [Handling API Error](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request), here is part of the explanation for `400 errors`

> This can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the
>   value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is
>   invalid.

This is because I have `alt:'media'` in my parameter object. 
I tried `gapi.client.drive.files.export`, but it doesn't work either and it returns `(403) Insufficient Permission` although my Google Drive account has the edit permission for those files. Here is my code:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    fileId:element.id,
});
request.then(function(resp){
    console.log(resp.result);
    type = resp.result.mimeType;
    id = resp.result.id;
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.export({
        fileId:id,
        mimeType:type
    })
    request.execute(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

**Update 1**

Based on [abielita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875835/3588080), I have tried to make an authorized HTTP request but it doesn't download the file. It actually returns the file information in `response` and `responseText` attribute in the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

```
  function test() {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+'1A1RguZpYFLyO9qEs-EnnrpikIpzAbDcZs3Gcsc7Z4nE', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
    xhr.send('alt=media');
  }
```

**______________________________________________________**

I found out that I can actually retrieve URLs of all those files from the folder using files' `webViewLink` or `webViewContent` attributes.

- A file which is from Google Drive type (Google Doc, Google Sheet,
  etc...) will have `webViewLink` attribute. A `webViewLink` will open
  the file in Google Drive.
- A non Google Drive type file will have `webContentLink`.  A
  `webContentLink` will download the file.

My code:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    q:"'0Bz9_vPIAWUcSWWo0UHptQ005cnM' in parents", //folder ID
    'fields': "files(id, name, webContentLink, webViewLink)"
  });
request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_has_not_granted_the_app_appid_verb_access_to_the_file_fileid

Comment: @BrianDHall I already read those, but those didn't help me much because they suggest to use something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file), if you're using `alt=media`, you need to make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's [`resource URL`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) and include the query parameter `alt=media`.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples) the examples of performing a file download with our Drive API client libraries.

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

For the error **(403) Insufficient Permission**, maybe this is a problem with your access token, not with your project configuration.

The insufficient permissions error is returned when you have not requested the scopes you need when you retrieved your access token. You can check which scopes you have requested by passing your access_token to this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Check these links:

- [google plus api: "insufficientPermissions" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978192/google-plus-api-insufficientpermissions-error)
- [Google drive Upload returns - (403) Insufficient Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075595/google-drive-upload-returns-403-insufficient-permission)

  > Remember you are uploading to the service accounts google drive account. If you want to be able to see it from your own Google drive account you are going to have to do an insert of the permissions. to give yourself access

Answer (score 7):

Phu, you were so close!

Thank you for sharing your method of using the webContentLink and webViewLink. I think that is best for most purposes. But in my app, I couldn't use viewContentLink because need to be able to enter the image into a canvas, and the image google provides is not CORS ready.

So here is a method

```js
var fileId = '<your file id>';
var accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;// or this: gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+fileId+'?alt=media', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
xhr.onload = function(){
    //base64ArrayBuffer from https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841
    var base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64ArrayBuffer(xhr.response);

    //do something with the base64 image here

}
xhr.send();
```

Notice that I set the response type to `arraybuffer`, and moved `alt=media` up to the `xhr.open` call. Also I grabbed a function that converts the array buffer to base64 from https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841.

Comment: This is gold! I've been trying to accomplish this for weeks! Note that if you're making multiple requests asynchronously it will replace `xhr.response` with a later response, so `this.response` should be used in this case.

Comment: this worked for me.
further code for downloading the image =>
//do something with the base64 image here
                        var imageToDownload = document.createElement("a");
                        imageToDownload.href = base64;
                        imageToDownload.download = "Image.png";
                        imageToDownload.click();

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I can actually retrieve URLs of all those files from the folder using files' 
`webViewLink` or `webViewContent` attributes. A file which is of Google Drive type (Google Doc, Google Sheet, etc...) will have `webViewLink` attribute and a non Google Drive type file will have `webContentLink`. The `webViewLink` will open the file in Google Drive and the `webContentLink` will download the file. My code:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    q:"'0Bz9_vPIAWUcSWWo0UHptQ005cnM' in parents", //folder ID
    fields: "files(id, name, webContentLink, webViewLink)"
});
request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp); //access to files in this variable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Task**: download the file and create File object;
**Environment**: browser;

```js
const URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files';
const FIELDS = 'name, mimeType, modifiedTime';

const getFile = async (fileId) => {
  const { gapi: { auth, client: { drive: { files } } } } = window;
  const { access_token: accessToken } = auth.getToken();
  const fetchOptions = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } };
  
  const {
    result: { name, mimeType, modifiedTime }
  } = await files.get({ fileId, fields: FIELDS });
  
  const blob = await fetch(`${URL}/${fileId}?alt=media`, fetchOptions).then(res => res.blob());
  const fileOptions = {
    type: mimeType,
    lastModified: new Date(modifiedTime).getTime(),
  };
  
  return new File([blob], name, fileOptions);
};
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Kirill, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download using the `files.get` API:

```
var fileId = '<your file id>';
gapi.client.drive.files.get(
    {fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'}
).then(function (response) {
    // response.body has the file data
}, function (reason) {
    alert(`Failed to get file: ${reason}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

let url = `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${file_id}&export=download`;

Make sure to pass the file_id in this link.
You can get the file id from the file you want to download by getlink --> general access. Make sure the file is public.