# Wordpress - Download GDrive file with Guzzle and display the body response in the browser

Tags: php, wordpress, google-drive-api, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle for downloading a PDF file from Google Drive.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/MyID?alt=media
```

I correctly get the response with

```
$response["body"]->getContents()
```

The content looks like:

```
%PDF-1.5
%????
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(es-ES) /StructTreeRoot 88 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 9/Kids[ 3 0 R 12 0 R 17 0 R 30 0 R 40 0 R 44 0 R 51 0 R 
58 0 R 60 0 R] >>
endobj
...
```

I'm calling this script from a link (href="this_script"), but I don't know what to do with that response, how can the user view this file in other browser tab or how to download this file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to view the file, try using **`webContentLink`** as suggested in the [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#viewing_files_in_a_browser). For downloading, try checking this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875835/5995040). Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot use webContentLink as the users don't have permissions on that file, so I need to call the API and download the file. I have added the stream and the content-type in an array, but when I send with *wp_send_json_success* to my JS function to display the *Blob* the encoding is lost. The PDF is visible, with the right number of pages, but with no content :-O

Comment: you are downloading the raw content to JavaScript, so your JavaScript must then take responsibility to render the content. Maybe a JS pdf library like https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ would work. Alternatively, you could get the content serverside and place it into a temporary file/buffer which you could then download.