# Creating new folder in Google Drive Fails with Insufficent Permission

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create new folder MY_FOLDER in Google Drive using Drive API, using the quick starter example and adding more to it as I read through the https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet.

My scope is set as:

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
```

And I create service like this

```
private static void CreateService()
{
    using (var stream =
        new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Drive API service.
    service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
}
```

As per example on this page [https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder], [2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder), I am creating new folder

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "MY_FOLDER",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
};
var request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
request.Fields = "id";
var file = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Folder ID: " + file.Id);
```

The error I get reads "**Insufficient Permissions [403]**"

UPDATE
I created credentials as described in same Google tutorial at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add your API credentials properly. I would double check on that.

Comment: or maybe the *debug* version is not authorized

Comment: I am doing it using the explanation in the link above in the UPDATE section.

Comment: Make sure that you grant the service account permission to access the file. You may refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075595/google-drive-upload-returns-403-insufficient-permission). You could also try changing your Google Drive Scope to `Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE`. Here's a related [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309136/google-drive-api-client-python-insufficient-permission-for-files-insert) which might help.